# Time.now & Created_at are different? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My site is deployed on heroku. Time.now will return today, but the created_at field of a record (created right now) will say its tomorrow. I assume this has to do with server time?

Is there a way to make sure they're the same?
Best,
Elliot

---

Update so I did this "heroku rake time:zones:us"

it gave me:

```
    * UTC -10:00 *
Hawaii

* UTC -09:00 *
Alaska

* UTC -08:00 *
Pacific Time (US & Canada)

* UTC -07:00 *
Arizona
Mountain Time (US & Canada)

* UTC -06:00 *
Central Time (US & Canada)

* UTC -05:00 *
Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Indiana (East)
```

however, when I set config.time_zone = 'UTC -05:00' in my environment, the app fails to start. any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to use either 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' or 'Indiana (East)' to set the time zone as those are the names for UTC -05:00.  Also, it's best to call Time.current instead of Time.now when config.time_zone has been set.

Comment: Hi:

The names for the time zones are what appears BELOW the UTC specifications. For instance, use:

   config.time_zone = 'Indiana (East)'

As Corey says, using Time.current (or Time.zone.now) will yield a time adjusted for the timezone you configured. In general, you can use any of the methods for Time you're used to, but you should call them on Time.zone which takes your timezone into account. This is of course rails-related; it won't work on plain Ruby without ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rails always stores UTC time on the database; the created_at field by itself should be offset by exactly your timezone's variation relative to UTC.

Whenever you load a record in your application, the fields get converted to the timezone specified in environment.rb. It might have something like this:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

For the time to be converted properly to your timezone, you might change this configuration setting to one matching your actual time zone. For instance:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

To see available zones, issue "rake -D time" on your rails directory. This will give you instructions on how to get time zone names for use in configuration.

Comment: Hi Roadmaster, thanks for the response, I tried it and received the updated error

Comment: I believe you need to do this in the application.rb not the environment.rb

Answer (score 1):

To add onto Roadmaster's answer, I had a similar challenge: the normal Rails timestamps were stored based on UTC in the database, but I needed to query to find *all records created today* according to the local time zone.

The query looked like this:

```
completions.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
  Date.today, Date.today + 1.day).count >= 1
```

I fixed this by calling `#to_time` on the dates, as follows. This converted them into a timestamp having the proper time zone, and the correct records were fetched in the database, effectively making the query timezone-aware.

```
completions.where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
  Date.today.to_time, Date.today.to_time + 1.day).count >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to uncomment and change to the time zone you wanna.

If you want to check all the time zone, run `rake time:zones:all` and will output a list.

```
config/Application.rb

module Clerk
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'La Paz'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to lines of code. I wanted the **created_at** to be on the **ActiveRecord** data creation.

```
config/Application.rb

module RailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'


  end
end
```