# What are the implications of changing config.time_zone in a live Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a Rails 4 app that has been running for a few months.

What are the implications of setting config.time_zone?

I don't want to screw up any delayed jobs, or calculations involving created_ats, etc., and don't see anywhere in the documentation where it explains what changing config.time_zone would do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.time_zone` is just how your app displays the data. Whenever times are stored in the database they are in UTC. Rails automatically converts the time in the database to your configured time whenever the record is loaded. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2512481/1905235)

This means that the only affect on your server should be the datetimes in HTML being generated. However, it's advised to store and render all times in UTC and then allow the client to convert them to local time due to the difficulty of determining what timezone a user has configured. This is a popular project that lets you do exactly that: https://github.com/basecamp/local_time

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it can only affect input and output of time, everything saved should have already been saved in UTC, but only testing+staging can completely answer this question concerning your application...